# Weird error in MacOSX 10.12.6 with Virtualenv and Python 3.7

Tags: macos, virtualenv, python-3.7

When attempting to create a new virtualenv with the following command:

```
~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3 graphenv
```

I get the following error:

```
New python executable in /Users/reinose/vinkapi/graphql/graphenv/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/reinose/vinkapi/graphql/graphenv/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/reinose/vinkapi/graphql/graphenv/bin/python3.7 could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/reinose/vinkapi/graphql/graphenv/bin/python3.7'
```

I also get a popup as displayed in the attached image ..

[image]

This is bewilldering ...

I can run other Python3 apps just fine ....

This only seems to happen when trying to create virtualenvs

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`?

Comment: It works with sudo ..... very weird ... why would it require sudo?

Comment: Depends on who *you* are currently acting as, along with various permissions. Most likely the ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv can only be executed by an admin in this case because you're affecting a different user's folder?

Comment: up until the use of sudo, I was acting as myself.

Comment: See my answer; it's hard to be sure with only these lines of output. I want to avoid [answering in a comment or secondary discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo`:

```
sudo ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3 graphenv
```

---

Why?

You likely need superuser access in this case because the environment that you normally run `python3` from is not the same as the environment that you're calling `virtualenv` from. Elevated access may be required because you're in the `~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv` path instead of where you normally run `python3`, perhaps here (your own user folder):

```
/Users/reinose/vinkapi/graphql/graphenv/bin/python3.7
```

...as that's where the new `virtualenv` is being created, from what I can tell.